# Business logic with CouchDB

Tags: javascript, couchdb, pouchdb

I need to design an offline-first application with sync capabilities so I decided to go with **CouchDB**. Since I will deploy this application on user's workstation he/she has the capability to tamper with data (in his/her local database e.g. **PouchDB**). AFAIK, **CouchDB** only offers validation functions (which only has access to incoming document, its previous version and userCtx) to avoid this, but most of the times this validation depends on the business logic. Is there any way to manage this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, if the user tampers the "local" db, its modifications will be deleted when the sync occurs (if the remote db is the master).
Or if you choose 2 ways sync, the master db is modified by the user...